# Navigate to a page in .Net MAUI Anroid Activity

Tags: android, maui

Missing something very basic here. I was successful in creating an activity which can be reached via an intent from another app, but for the life of me I have been unable to figure out how to navigate to a page from this bit of code.

My goal is just to show an Image. I can retrieve the image in the code just fine as a base64 or a local storage, and my plan was to navigate to a page with an  section, but no matter what I do I can't seem to navigate. Currently trying to go to the default Main Page

```cs
[Activity(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(
    actions: new[] { Intent.ActionSend },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        bundle ??= Intent?.Extras;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        
        // doesn't work
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
        // doesn't work
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(MainPage)}");
        // doesn't work
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///MainPage");
        
        // also doesn't work
        var eventAggregator = ServiceHelper.GetService<EventAggregator>();
        eventAggregator.RaiseNavigateToMain();
        
        var response = new Bundle();
        response.PutString("response", "OK");
        SetResult(Result.Ok, new Intent().PutExtras(response));
    }
}
```

```cs
// in App.xaml.cs
public App(EventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
        
        eventAggregator.Requests += OnNavigateToMain;
    }

// the below is reachable and does execute, and I can even debug and see that Shell.Current is fine, but still doesn't navigate
private async void OnNavigateToMain()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
    }
```

The EventAggregator just calls `.Invoke` on the event.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you need to make sure that the navigation occurs on the main ui thread. Also, it is assume you're using AppShell and the pages are properly registered, you should include that code so that we can confirm that it is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the navigation in the main ui thread like LoadingPage.Xaml.cs. Here is the demo you can refer to:

```
public partial class LoadingPage : ContentPage
{
      public LoadingPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)

    {

        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//LoginPage");

    }
}
```

More information you can check in this page [.NET MAUI Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation).